# Spring.Net Strong Naming

Tags: spring.net

Can someone comment why Spring.NET libraries (Spring.Core, Spring.Services, Spring.Data, Spring.Data.NHibernate33) for Spring.NET 2.0.0.0 M2 release on Nuget are not strong name signed? I need to use these libraries in a COM+ project.

I am unable to register on Spring.NET community forum (the verification text image does not show up).

I think this must be an oversight/bug since there are similar issues in the spring.net forums for a previous release.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a suitable question for SO. If their forum fails you, consider filing an issue at their [Jira issue tracker](https://jira.springsource.org/secure/BrowseProject.jspa?id=10020) or at [Github project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/issues).

Comment: I have opened an issue on JIRA issue tracker - https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPRNET-1565. I would like to keep this open in case there is a technical reason for not signing the assemblies. If it turns out otherwise I will delete this question.